# Maths expression in inequality during data.table join

Tags: r, data.table

I want to perform a conditional join in [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table). Specifically, I want to join where `b` from `dt2` is within the interval `[a - 0.5, a + 0.5)` from `dt1`. I can do this by defining columns that bound the interval then perform the join, like below.

```r
library(data.table)

# Create dummy data tables
dt1 <- data.table(a = 1:10, value  = runif(10))
dt1[, `:=`(l = a - 0.5, u = a + 0.5)]

dt2 <- data.table(b = 2.2)

# Examine data tables
dt1
#>      a      value   l    u
#>  1:  1 0.48090204 0.5  1.5
#>  2:  2 0.66158820 1.5  2.5
#>  3:  3 0.97218996 2.5  3.5
#>  4:  4 0.20709244 3.5  4.5
#>  5:  5 0.01498827 4.5  5.5
#>  6:  6 0.36731224 5.5  6.5
#>  7:  7 0.40613311 6.5  7.5
#>  8:  8 0.47610796 7.5  8.5
#>  9:  9 0.76508944 8.5  9.5
#> 10: 10 0.69465174 9.5 10.5
dt2
#>      b
#> 1: 2.2

# Perform conditional join
# This works
dt1[dt2, .(a, b, value, x.u, x.l), on = .(l <= b, u > b)]
#>    a   b     value x.u x.l
#> 1: 2 2.2 0.6615882 2.5 1.5
```

My question is, do I *have* to define these columns before the join or can I include a mathematical expression in the inequality? My attempt below clearly doesn't work, but I wondered if there is a way of doing this.

```r
# This does not work
dt1[dt2, .(a, b, value), on = .(a - 0.5 <= b, a + 0.5 > b)]
#> Error in `[.data.table`(dt1, dt2, .(a, b, value), on = .(a - 0.5 <= b, : Column(s) [a - 0.5,a + 0.5] not found in x
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yes, you have to define these columns before the non-equi join.

Comment: Not data.table but in SQL you can do this: `library(sqldf); sqldf("select *
  from dt1
  left join dt2 on b between a - 0.5 and a + 0.5")`

Comment: Related open FR: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1639